# Script HTTPS call for vulnerability test verification

Tags: https, openssl

I'm trying to demonstrate to our QA department that we have (or have not) fixed a vulnerability shown in a recent scan.  I would like to write a simple script that can demonstrate the vulnerability and show that the remediation actually fixes it.  However since the vulnerability involves a invalid (possibly intentionally) HTTPS request I can't use a standard client to easily replicate it.  Because there are several servers to test and several different vulnerabilities I would like to automate the testing a bit.

The following command line replicates the test but requires human intervention:

```
>openssl s_client -connect {server:ip} | grep Location
GET /images HTTP/1.0 <---- (user types this plus two Enter keys)

Location:{text here proves success/failure}
```

**How can I automate the test above?**

I'm using openssl because it's convenient.  I'm willing to get another tool if it can accept arbitrary HTTPS request headers.

Comment: WFETCH in Raw Request mode? You can probably script that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can just pipe your text into the OpenSSL command-line utility:

```
printf 'GET /images HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | openssl s_client -connect {server:ip} | grep Location
```